# Uboot - Checking validity of the U-Boot environment

Tags: environment, u-boot

could someone share some info on "if and how the U-Boot checks the validity of the environment block"?

Example:
There are 2 U-Boot environments, env 1 (main) and env2 (redundant). An update of the env 1 has been interrupted, hence it is invalid. How does the U-Boot knows the env 1 one is invalid and that it needs to read environment variables from the env 2?

Cheers

Comment: There's a CRC32 value to validate the environment area.

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot can store the environment in different places depending on the configuration. Separate drivers are supplied. Some drivers use CRC32 to check the integrity of the environment, e.g. env/nvram.c.